# Can't start gpg-agent for .gnupg folder stored inside a Veracrypt encrypted container

Tags: macos, gpg, veracrypt

I have my `.gnupg` directory inside a USB drive encrypted with Veracrypt. Listing the public keys with the `gpg --homedir <path-to-usb-gnupg-dir> --list-keys` works properly, but problems arise when trying to list the private keys with `--list-secret-keys`:

```
~ % gpg --homedir <path-to-usb-gnupg-dir> --list-secret-keys
gpg: error running '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.4.3/bin/gpg-agent': exit status 2
gpg: failed to start gpg-agent '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.4.3/bin/gpg-agent': General error
gpg: can't connect to the gpg-agent: General error
gpg: error running '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.4.3/bin/gpg-agent': exit status 2
gpg: failed to start gpg-agent '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.4.3/bin/gpg-agent': General error
gpg: can't connect to the gpg-agent: General error
```

I suppose this was because the mounted container's file and directory permissions were incorrect, and found out that Veracrypt has an `--fs-options` command ([also discussed in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372950/change-permissions-for-mounted-veracrypt-drive-in-linux)). The problem is that this command doesn't apparently work on MacOS as running it generates the following error:

```
Unknown long option 'fs-options'
Error: Incorrect command line specified.
```

I also tried to symlink the `.gnupg` directory to my home folder with `ln -s <path-to-usb-gnupg-dir> ~/.gnupg-usb`, but the error persisted. Is there any possible workarounds for this setup?